# Unable to find out why oozie job remains in Running state

Tags: oozie

WE are facing issue with Oozie where the Oozie job is launched and it goes into running state. The oozie job is a sqoop job internally that connects mysql and imports a tabledata into hdfs. The internal sqoop job works fine when run independantly. The jar files mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar is located in the hdfs folders /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180601073112/oozie and /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180601073112/sqoop

WE are running oozie on Cloudera 5.14.2

Comment: It will be easy if you can share your Oozie code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><workflow-app name="Sqoop_Test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5"> <start to="sqoop-9420"/> <action name="sqoop-9420">  <sqoop  xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker> <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>  <command>job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<ipconfig>:16000/sqoop --exec mysql_hadoopdb_customers -- --password hduser</command>  </sqoop> <ok to="End"/> <error to="kill"/> </action> <kill name="kill">    <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message> </kill>  <end name="End"/>